# how to get rid of automatic space around header image

Tags: css

i have an image header and i want it to go across the entire top of the page. the problem is there is automatic space being created around the image and the top/sides of the screen. how can i get rid of this? i have a feeling im missing something really simple.

an example of what i want is the header on [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/).

HTML:

```
<body>
<img id="topbar-img" src="img/topbar.jpg" />
<div id="topbar">asdf</div>
<!-- jq() loads jquery if it cant connect to online version. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jq();
</script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-image:url('../img/bg.jpg');
}

div#topbar
{
}

img#topbar-img
{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
position:absolute;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the padding and margin for the body element to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
body { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```